# Evaluating $\int \cos(x) \sqrt{\sin(2 x)} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate the following indefinite integral:
>
> $$\int \cos(x) \sqrt{\sin(2 x)} dx$$

Only hint I have is from W|A that expresses the integral in terms of a hypergeometric function and it looks rather ugly.
Can we solve it in a simpler way and get a nicer form?  Thanks.

Comment: I get a [WA expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BCos%5Bx%5D+Sqrt%5BSin%5B2x%5D%5D%2Cx%5D) that only involves elementary functions...

Comment: @Fabian: yeah. I did things in a hurry and I didn't wait W|A for providing with complete information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int {\cos x\sqrt {\sin 2x} dx}  &=& \int {\cos x\sqrt {2\sin x\cos x} dx}  \\ 
   &=& \sqrt 2 \int {\sqrt {\cos x\sin x} \cos xdx}  \\
  \begin{cases}\sin x = u\\ \cos xdx = du\end{cases}  \\  
   &=& \sqrt 2 \int {{u^{1/2}}{{\left( {1 - {u^2}} \right)}^{1/4}}} du \end{eqnarray*} $$

Do you know how to integrate [differential binomials](http://planetmath.org/IntegrationOfDifferentialBinomial.html)?

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107035/how-to-calculate-integral-of-int-0-sqrt34-sqrt-fracx4-x-frac32/146558#146558) answer of mine. Since

$$\frac{{m + 1}}{n} + p = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = 1$$ is an integer, you should be able to integrate this in terms of elementary functions with the instructions provided in the answer I linked to. Letting $u^2=z$ gives

$$ = \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{2}\int {{{\left( {\frac{{1 - z}}{z}} \right)}^{1/4}}} dz$$

Now let $$\frac{{1 - z}}{z} = {m^4}$$ whence $$dz = \frac{{4{m^3}dm}}{{{{\left( {{m^4} + 1} \right)}^2}}}$$

and get

$$ = 2\sqrt 2 \int {\frac{{{m^4}}}{{{{\left( {{m^4} + 1} \right)}^2}}}dm} $$ which is a treatable rational function.

Comment: For $\pi \le x \le 3\pi/2$ we have $\sin(2x) \ge 0$, but $\sin(x),\cos(x) \le 0$, and therefore $\cos(x)=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$!

Comment: @Mercy There is always handwavingness when finding primitives, I know. But things usually work out.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, rewrite
$$I=\sqrt{2}\int(1-(\sin x)^2)^\frac{1}{4}(\sin{x})^\frac{1}{2}d(\sin{x})\\=\sqrt{2}\int(1-t^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}t^\frac{1}{2}dt\\=\sqrt{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{t^2}-1\right)^\frac{1}{4}tdt \\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\left(\frac{1}{z}-1\right)^\frac{1}{4}dz$$
Now let
$$\frac{1}{z}-1=u^2$$
$$-\frac{dz}{z^2}=2udu$$
$$dz=-\frac{2udu}{(1+u^2)^2}=d\left(\frac{1}{1+u^2}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{2}I=\int u^\frac{1}{2}d\left(\frac{1}{1+u^2}\right)=\frac{u^\frac{1}{2}}{1+u^2}-\int\frac{d\left(u^\frac{1}{2}\right)}{1+u^2}$$
Where the last integral is equivalently $\int\frac{dv}{1+v^4}$ to which there exist [various approaches](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160157/integration-of-int-frac1x41dx?rq=1).

Comment: Linebreaks `\\\` are useful for long chains of equalities.

Comment: thanks, will note for future

Comment: @Valentin: OK, thanks! (+1)